# Calculate Sum of values from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to calculate the sum of all rating values(float) that is in the nodes of Firebase database and wants to show in the text box.

**Firebase Database**

[Firebase DATABASE Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwZ9j.jpg)
Rating values i want to retrieve. I want sum of all the rating values and save that sum value in the text box.
Here is what i done 
**Database Class**

```
public class databaseReview {
String description,name,userImage;
String rating;

public  databaseReview(){

}
public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(String rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public databaseReview(String rating, String description) {
    this.rating = rating;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getuserImage() {
    return userImage;
}

public void setuserImage(String userImage) {
    this.userImage = userImage;
}
```

}

**Java Class**

```
                 DatabaseReference dataReference =   
               FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
              getReference().child("Feedbacks").child(name);
      dataReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            for( DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                databaseReview data = ds.getValue(databaseReview.class);


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `Feedbacks` node is a direct child of your Firebase root and the `name` variable has its value as `Abasyn University Islamabad`, to count all the ratings, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference nameRef = rootRef.child("Feedbacks").child(name);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        double count = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double rating = ds.child("rating").getValue(Double.class);
            count = count + rating;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", count + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
nameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

But be aware, this will work only if the `raiting` property is stored in your database as a `double`. Your screenshot is correct but your model class shows:

```
String rating;
```

Comment: getting error on address variable -- Log.d("count", address);

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Please see my updated answer together with my updated text.

Comment: Ok i get it let me try but what is Double.class? in it? is it the name of database class?

Comment: No, we are passing `Double.class` as an argument to `getValue()` method to indicate the result that we are getting is a Double. Its the same as: `double rating = (Double) ds.child("rating").getValue();`

Comment: you did not link the nameRef with onDataChange? How will he know the reference?

Comment: I have added the listener using this line of code: `nameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);` Am I missing somethig? Have you tried my code? Do you any error now?

Comment: nameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener); check your code where you wrote this line? :/

Comment: Is as the last line on my code. Right after the last `};`. You cannot see it?

Comment: Ok Sorry i get it last thing? where you use the name of database class from where double rating is initialized and get Rating function?

Comment: There is no need to use that. To only count those rating, Double class is enough. So, does it work now?

Comment: i think its because while i pushing the value it is in form of string look
String rating= String.valueOf(mRatingBar.getRating());
 myRef.child("rating").setValue(rating);

Comment: That's right. You need to add the rating as a double. Change that and say if it works.